# Questions disguised as FOIA requests

Tags: foia

I was reading an opinion in HUDGINS V. I.R.S., (D.D.C. 1985) regarding the ruling that the government is not required to answer "questions disguised as FOIA requests."

https://casetext.com/case/hudgins-v-irs

I think this view is entirely wrong.  In my view, it is not the fact that a FOIA request appears to be a question which disqualifies the FOIA request.  The only thing that can disqualify a FOIA request is the fact that "records" are not "reasonably described."

I am currently requesting from my state attorney general's office the "laws which are being used to justify X actions by the executive."

While it is true that this could be rephrased as a question, it does not fail to 1) "reasonably describe" 2) "records".  Since I am asking the attorney general's office, they are either using laws to justify a course of action or they are not.  If they are, then they know what records I mean.  *That* is reasonably describing.  And of course, laws are records.  If they are not using laws to justify their actions, then of course they do not know what I mean.  In that case, the law provides that they should say so.

Either way, you see the trap here, do you not?

The question: Based upon more than just Hudgins, is there anything to support my FOIA/FOAA(Maine) request as being valid?

My jurisdiction is Maine

Comment: It seems to me that your request is *exactly* the sort of "disguised question" that the ruling discusses.  If they just sent you a link to the complete set of the state's laws, they have certainly included those which are used to justify X actions, so taken literally your request is satisfied.  The only way that won't satisfy you is if you are not actually asking for *records*, but are asking the question: *Which* laws are used to justify X actions?  And I don't think FOIA creates an obligation for the state to answer that question for you.

Comment: Does a federal FOIA case even apply to a claim under a state law?

Comment: @NateEldredge Here's the problem though. Even if they gave me a link to all of the laws, that would have to mean there was a law inside all of the laws that justified what they were doing. My point is that there is no law to justify what they're doing. So by presenting what you suggested, they would in effect be lying. And lying is against lawyer ethics.

Comment: @cpast FOIA cases would only be used as a comparison where there is a lack of state precedent for it's own access law

Comment: @cpast - FOIA only applies to the U.S. government; but as Mr.A points out, that caselaw could be useful and persuasive to a court deciding an issue under the freedom of information laws in its own jurisdiction.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you have misinterpreted the case, not least because the Hudgins v I.R.S case involves this only peripherally. The original case [Diviaio v Kelly](https://casetext.com/case/diviaio-v-kelley#p542) was dealing with a request for the *number* of photographs taken of the plaintiff and if these had been disseminated outside the CIA. This is in no way shape or form a request for records (the records were found to be legitimately exempt).

I see no problem in your FOI request. In fact, I can foresee the response:

> These, http://www.maine.gov/legis/ros/meconlaw.htm, are the laws we use to justify these actions.

In a common law jurisdiction, a person (including the government) does not have to prove they are abiding by the law. The onus is on you to prove they aren't; they do not have to help you make your case.

Comment: Here's the problem though.  Even if they gave me a link to all of the laws, that would have to mean there was a law inside all of the laws that justified what they were doing.  My point is that there is no law to justify what they're doing.  So by presenting what you suggested, they would in effect be lying.  And lying is against lawyer ethics.

Comment: I think this is a good answer! I would like to add but one thing but don't like to edit people's answers.There is an important distinction between FOIA (The Freedom Of information Act) and FOAA (Maine's Freedom of Access Act). They both deal with requesting information from the government, but likely have different requirements, exemptions, and case law interpreting their meaning. FIOA is only for the U.S. government, while FOAA is only for Maine.

Comment: @Mr.A - I hear your argument. Perhaps if you gave us more information on what you are requesting we could suggest general strategies to request information.

Comment: @Mr_Vitale - Well I want to see the law that justifies having 3-2 votes or 2-0 votes or 1-0 votes with three abstentions...on five seven or up to even nine member licensing boards.  There is no law.  My goal is to force the attorneys to admit that fact.  It's all common law.  That's objective number one.  Force them to admit there is no law.  The FOAA provides that when a request is denied, the reasons for denying the request must be stated.  I want to request the law and have it be denied, with the stated reason being that the law does not exist.

Comment: @Mr.A - Sounds like a something where it will be difficult to get an answer through FOAA. If you fdo go the information act request route, Consider asking for e-mail communications, written documents, memorandum, etc. that were used in deciding that the votes by the licensing board were valid. Don't most committees/licensing boards require a quorum?

Comment: @Mr_Vitale 1-0 with 3 abstentions will normally meet a requirement that there be a quorum of 4, because 4 members were present. It also means the measure passes, because a majority normally means majority of people present and voting.

Comment: @Mr.A You could ask for the rules of procedure used by the board. However, it's extremely likely that they allow what you think they don't. Typically, abstentions count towards any quorum requirement, but are not counted when determining if a measure passes. So, if you have enough members present to have a quorum and all but one abstain on a question, and that one member votes for the motion, the motion will pass unless the threshold is not in terms of "members present and voting." Normally, thresholds *are* in terms of members present and voting.

Comment: @cpast this is getting a bit off topic, but 1) there are no rules of procedure.  2) I've examined minutes from board to board and have found one inconsistency.  That is, a motion to approve the minutes failed in one board to pass with a 2-0 vote with 2 abstaining.  But a motion to put a letter of guidance in a licensee's file passed 3-2 with one abstaining in another board.  In either case, there wasn't a majority of the quorum voting in the affirmative.  But in the second case, the motion passed.  That suggests a discrepancy in enforcement that I intend to exploit.

Comment: @Mr.A If you gave what boards you were talking about, it'd be very helpful. And how do you know there are no rules of procedure? Have you asked? Because they definitely have *some* way of determining whether a motion passed or not.

Comment: @cpast - Maine Electricians and the Maine Land Surveyors were the two boards I just respectively cited.  They don't have rules of procedure.  It's all ad hoc.  The board attorneys decide what's acceptable.  It's an absolute outrage.

Comment: @Mr.A So they confirmed they make it all up as they go? And in which one did a motion to approve the minutes fail 2-0?

Comment: @cpast - Of course they won't "confirm" it.  But Im just looking at the minutes.  The electrician's board wouldn't approve minutes with a 2-0 vote with 2 abstaining.  Back in December I believe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36321/discussion-between-cpast-and-mr-a).